# Is it possible to combine Modify and Draw interaction in OpenLayers?

Tags: angular, openlayers

In my current Angular project I have implemented the Draw, Modify, Select, Snap, Translate interactions, as well as some ol-ext functionalities, but a new requirement arose: I need that when the user begins to modify the position of an element type Point, it generates a guide line that starts at the original position of the element. When Modify interaction is done, the line that was created should be deleted (that's the easy part).

I think that it is possible, since I can detect when the user initiates the modification, but it isn't clear to me how to combine it with the Draw interaction, because in normal situations, you can't combine both interactions (Draw and Modify) at same time. If you modify an existent element, Draw interaction funcionality doesn't works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you need to "draw" the line?  You could simply style a line while the point was being modified https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-sfhpf

Comment: I need to draw a Line (just because the user needs to know the element to which the element is originally assigned) at same time I'm modifying an element tipe Point, My main interaction event is Modify

Comment: The line itself is never finished digitizing. It only works as a guide so that the user knows that even when they move the position of an elemento type Point, it's still associated with another element.

Comment: Sorry Mike, your example was not working in my browser. I think it could works. Let me verify

Comment: Have you look at the ol-ext  interaction SnapGuide that generate tempory guides while drawing/modifying? See example: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.snapguides.html

Comment: Mike, thanks for your help. I just need to make a few changes because in my style function I was getting a FeatureLike type and I had to cast feature.getGeometry() as a Point and use getFlatCoordinates() instead of getCoordinates() (can't find that function implemented). Could you answer as an answer instead of a comment? To mark it as a valid answer, please